# setting contentOffset and calling loadHTMLWithString resets it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView and I want to set the contentOffset and after that I had a call to loadHTMLWithString and it resets back the contentOffset that I've set, is there any way that I can avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I get it right, you first set `contentOffset` and THEN `loadHTMLString:`?

Why not the other way around?

Comment: because it will animate when I do that and I don't want to have the transision seen

Comment: yea and it even looks even worse as it appears as a sudden

Comment: So you want to animate (say) to the top, then reload the page and then scroll back to the original position? You could play around with `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:` in the `UIScrollViewDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

I tried several workarounds for the same problem, and seems setContentOffset does not work well for UIVebView. Something always reset it to (0,0).

Finally setContentInset property helped me a lot:

```
[self.webView.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 160.0)];
```

Then use UIWebViewDelegate and set content offset in the method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [self.webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(160, 0)];
}
```